# Referring to a website in `bibtex`

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am referring to a website in a scientific paper, the website is providing some stats.

What do I write in the `author` field? The stats are collected using programs installed on some players PCs.

I am using `natbib` in my `tex` files. I am generating the `bibtex` file using mendeley.

This is the website: http://www.xfire.com/cms/xstatics_2009_february/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try the `@misc` bibTeX entry. As `author` I'd take 'Xfire', as `title` something like 'Top 20 most played games on Xfire' and the `howpublished` field should contain the link to the website:

```
@misc{Xfire,
author={Xfire},
title={Top 20 most played games on Xfire},
howpublished={\url{http://www.xfire.com/cms/xstatics_2009_february/}}
}
```

Note that you'll need to call the `url` package in the preamble

Comment: or package `hyperref`, which includes the call of package `url`.