# Referring to a website with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, urls

I'm referring to a website using the **ieeetr** bibliography style. Therefore, I tried the following:

```
@online{testwebsite,
author={Foo},
title={{Test Website}},
url={http://test.com},
urldate={2016-02-01},
}
```

I receive the following error: **Entry type for "..." isn't style-file defined** and it shows only the reference as follows: **[1] Foo, "Test Website."**, while I would like to show the URL of the website with the url date.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you really use the ancient `ieeetr` bibliography style, which dates back to 1985 (with minor changes applied in 1992) and which doesn't know about fields such as `url` and `urldate`? Are you free to switch to a more modern implementation, say, `IEEEtranN.bst` (which works with `natbib`)?

Comment: Yes, I'm free to choose, except that the style should be practically the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `@online` entry type in the `ieeetr` style, and `ieeetr` does neither support `url` nor `urldate` fields. You may use the `@misc` type with a `note` field, like

```
@misc{testwebsite,
    author={Foo},
    title={{Test Website}},
    note={\url{http://test.com}, accessed 2016-02-01},
}
```

Or, you can use the `howpublished` field for the url; see also [Referring to a website in `bibtex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50306/referring-to-a-website-in-bibtex).

As Mico [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325607/referring-to-a-website-with-bibtex#comment795864_325607), `ieeetr` is outdated. You should prefer `IEEEtran` (or `IEEEtranN` for `natbib` support).

`IEEEtran` supports an `electronic` entry type (however, this is a non-standard field and should be avoided if you want to be compatible with other style files).
`urldate` is also non-standard and should be avoided if you want to typeset it in a bibliography (imho — if you know what you are doing, that may be fine, of course).

If you use `IEEEtran` (or any other recent BibTeX style), you can use the `url` field for the actual URL and put the date in the `note` field, like this:

```
@misc{testwebsite,
    author={Foo},
    title={{Test Website}},
    url={http://test.com},
    note={accessed 2016-02-01},
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything work fine, except that the URL is not shown.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing some uppercasing issues. Hope that's OK.