# TeXStudio not changing Bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies

I want do display the url and accessed date of webpages I'm using in my Bibliography. Other than that it should just be IEEE conform.
I'm using TexLive, TexStudio and Zotero. I exported my collection with Zotero as BibTex (but also tried as BibLatex). But when I change \bibliographystyle it doens't have any effect. What can I do?

I'm using this template from my university: [LaTex Template](https://git.imp.fu-berlin.de/agse/thesis-template/repository/archive.zip?ref=master)

Examples:

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieee}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

While the bibliography looks like this:

```
@misc{rfc_datetime,
title = {{RFC} 3339 - {DateTime}},
url = {https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14},
urldate = {2017-09-05},
file = {Date and Time on the Internet\: Timestamps:C\:\\Users\\Alexander\\Zotero\\storage\\J3J4ZDBI\\rfc3339.html:text/html}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added the example and also linked to the template of my university that I am using. I'm very new to TeX.

Comment: I cannot find `ieee.bst` anywhere on CTAN. But perhaps this question will help: [Referring to a website with bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325607/referring-to-a-website-with-bibtex/325608)

Comment: Your "example" cannot be compiled. I does not have a documentclass, neither does it include any cite command, so it would not create any bibliography at all.

Comment: Sorry about that @samcarter. Could you have a look at the template I linked?